# How to Update a Select2 4.0 Collection Select Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I have a `collection_select` for clients with an option to add a new client using a modal. I would like the select2 `collection_select` to update with the new client and set the value to the newly added client.

Inside the parent form, I have:

```
<%= f.collection_select :client_id, @clients, :id, :name, { label: 'Client', prompt: true, autofocus: true, required_flag: true }, { class: 'form-control js-example-basic-single', autofocus: true } %>
<div class='form-group'>
  <%= link_to 'Add a New Client', '#new_client_modal', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>
</div>
```

In the clients controller I have:

```
@clients = Client.where(account_id: current_account.id)
format.html { redirect_to client_url(@client) }
format.js   { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @client }
```

In the show.js.erb I have:

```
$('#new_client_modal').modal_success();
$(".js-example-basic-single").val("<%=j @client.id.to_s %>").trigger("change");
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  $('#flash_messages').html("<%=j render 'layouts/error' %>")
<% end %>
```

The thought is to close the add client modal and then update the select2 collection select with the new @clients `options. The hope is to update the collection select with @clients and set the value to @client.

Note that I am using select2 version 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way but this is what I ended up with:

```
$(".js-example-basic-client").select2({
  data: [{ id: "<%=j @client.id.to_s %>", text: "<%=j @client.name %>" }],
  theme: "bootstrap"
});
$(".js-example-basic-client").val("<%=j @client.id.to_s %>").trigger("change");
```

The data command added the recently added client to the dropdown, but at the bottom. Ideally I would have to remove the dropdown options, and then add the complete list of clients. For now this works since setting the selected value to the recently added client.